# Repetitive answers of recursing method in python

Tags: python, recursion

I wrote simple recursive function:

```
def y(n):
    if n == 0:
        print("{} - {}".format(n, 0.182))
        return 0.182
    else:
        print("{} - {}".format(n, 1 / n - 5 * y(n - 1)))
        return 1 / n - 5 * y(n - 1)
```

And I can't get why it gave me messed up answers. Here is a sample:

```
0 - 0.182
1 - 0.09000000000000008
0 - 0.182
2 - 0.0499999999999996
0 - 0.182
1 - 0.09000000000000008
0 - 0.182
3 - 0.08333333333333531
0 - 0.182
1 - 0.09000000000000008
0 - 0.182
```

When I changed code to:

```
def y(n):
    if n == 0:
        result = 0.182
        print("{} - {}".format(n, result))
        return result
    else:
        result = 1 / n - 5 * y(n - 1)
        print("{} - {}".format(n, result))
        return result
```

It worked perfectly well. Why?

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? How are you calling it? Please provide more details. In any case, the first version calls itself recursively twice in the `else` body (once in the string formatting/print, another in the return), in the second version, it only calls itself recursively once (assigning to a local variable, then printing and returning the result). So that probably explains the behavior you are seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in this block:

```
else:
    print("{} - {}".format(n, 1 / n - 5 * y(n - 1)))
    return 1 / n - 5 * y(n - 1)
```

You are running the y twice (when printing and on return)

While in the second version:

```
result = 1 / n - 5 * y(n - 1)
print("{} - {}".format(n, result))
return result
```

You are executing y once.

Answer (score 0):

**All the error is due to the `else` part**

As andreis11 mentioned, you are passing values to your function `y()` twice

Try passing `1 / n - 5 * y(n - 1))` to a variable and just calling the function once.

```
result = 1 / n - 5 * y(n - 1)
print("{} - {}".format(n, result))
return result
```

Will do work, because of the same reason

Answer (score 0):

The error was in the last line of the code:

```
return 1 / n - 5 * y (n - 1)
```

You don't need to return anything because the print already gives the value you want.

try this:

```
def y(n):
    if n == 0:
        print("{} - {}".format(n, 0.182))
        return 0.182
    else:
        print("{} - {}".format(n, 1 / n - 5 * y(n - 1)))
```